# C# Get type of subClass and create object of this

Tags: c#

```
    class MainClass { 
      private int someMethod() { 
    IList <SubClass> obj = db.Query <SubClass> (delegate(SubClass obj) { 
      return obj.Points == 100; 
    });
}
    } 

    class SubClass : MainClass { 
        public int someField; 
    } 

    SubClass obj = new SubClass(); 
    obj.someMethod();
```

SubClasses can be differnt, i need get instance of this for make a query to db4o.

Comment: Are you looking for this class MainClass
    {
        public string someMethod()
        {
            //in context "this" - SubClass. if "this.getType()" its will be "namespace.SubClass"; 
            SubClass cls = new SubClass();
            return "";
        }
    }

    class SubClass : MainClass
    {
        public int someField;
    }

Comment: Building such kind of code will defeat the purpose of polymorphism. Make someMethod virtual and then get it implemented in each subclass.

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to do. You want a type to be able to reproduce itself?

Comment: Why would "this" in an object return a different object?

Comment: I need this for working with different SubClasses with db4o. For example

IList <SomeClass> obj = db.Query <SomeClass> (delegate(SomeClass obj) {
    return obj.Points == 100;
});

Comment: Almost sounds like you really need an *interface* if you have differing objects implementing a common set of methods? Perhaps you should describe your intent a bit more thoroughly so we can help you find a better solution.

Comment: question edited

Answer (score 0):

Evaluating subclass types from base class to make some processing, is generally a bad decision, consider adding a composed method to the base class, then leverage specialized processing to its subclass:

```
class MainClass {
    public string ComposedMethod(){
        //Base class processing...
        var retVal = someMethod();
        //Even more Base class processing...
        return retVal; 
    } 
    public virtual string someMethod(){ 
    } 
} 

class SubClass : MainClass { 
    public override string someMethod(){
        return this.GetType().ToString(); //Or whatever you need to do
    } 
}
```

Usage:

```
SubClass obj = new SubClass(); 
obj.ComposedMethod();
```

Comment: I need this for working with different SubClasses with db4o. For example 
private string someMethod() 
    { 
IList <SubClass> obj = db.Query <SubClass> (delegate(SubClass obj) { return obj.Points == 100; });
       return some string; 
    } 
i need get "SubClass", when one of SubClasses will take a method "someMethod".